# my registration form css is breaking after rending validation message on page

Tags: css, forms

This is my form before submission : 
[image]

This is my form after submission: 
[image]

This is what css have written for each field :

```
.form-group {
    margin: 2% 0% 0% 0%;
    padding: 1% 1% 0% 0%;
}
```

this css is for error message :

```
.error {
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

See, after rendering validation message the css is breaking and form height is getting expanded. 
How to manage this in minimal space so that my form will look good ?

Comment: looks like you have a fixed height for that picture, and your notification text is making the box bigger than the picture. make the picture be 100% height, or make it the background-image with `background-size:cover;`.

Comment: The notification text has some exceeding space below... probably a margin or a padding.

Comment: no issue with the background size it's marked 100% 100%(background-cover).. 
inspected with firebug, the text is not having any extra margin or padding.

Comment: Ajay, make a jsfiddle of that, it is either the img or its container height. Post the html/css code!

Answer (score 0):

The easy (not recommended) way would be:

```
.error {
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

See if the components still fall out of the image, if it does, decrease the line-height.
I strongly recommend to set other color, red is hard to read or put some background on it.